# What is the best way to enforce constraints across tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I often find myself running into situations like this one (which is contrived but illustrative of the problem):

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  type TEXT
  -- other columns...
);

CREATE TABLE product_order (
  id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  customer_id INTEGER REFERENCES customer (id),
  type        TEXT REFERENCES customer (type), -- not actually legitimate
  -- other columns...
  CHECK (type = 'business')
);
```

Of course, the foreign key constraint on `product_order.type` doesn't work because `customer.type` is not `UNIQUE` or a primary key (and I can't use a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` on a column that only exists in another table). However, I would only like `product_order` entries for `type = 'business'` customers.

I could make `customer.id` and `customer.type` a composite primary key, but then any other tables that want to reference just `customer.id` must also reference `customer.type` unnecessarily.

What's the best approach in this situation?

EDIT: Forgot the foreign key constraint `product_order.customer_id`!

Comment: Which dbms are you using here? (Some non-ANSI SQL...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a unique *constraint* on the `customer.type` you can reference it from the `product_order` table:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  type TEXT,
  -- other columns...
  constraint unique_cust_type unique (id, type) -- this makes the combination id/type "referencable"
);


CREATE TABLE product_order 
(
  id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  customer_id INTEGER,
  type        TEXT default 'business',
  CHECK (type = 'business'),
  foreign key (customer_id, type) references customer (id, type)
);
```

Comment: Making `type` unique doesn't quite work... Then I could only have one customer with `type = 'business'`!

Comment: @user1475412 you could make the combination id/type a unique constraint, then you can reference that _combination_ from the `product_order` table

Comment: This looks like the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a lookup table for types, and use the FKEY relationship to enforce

```
CREATE TABLE type (
  id   integer, PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE customer (
  id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  type_id INTEGER, NOT NULL
  -- other columns...
  FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES type(id)
);

CREATE TABLE product_order (
  id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  type_id INTEGER, NOT NULL
  -- other columns...
  FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES type(id)
);
```

Comment: I realize that I forgot a critical part of the question... I need `product_order` to reference `customer` (so that the only records in `product_order` reference a `customer` record with `type = 'business'`).

Answer (score 0):

You could access product_order as a view:

```
create view product_order_vw
as
select po.* 
from product_order po
join customer c
on c.customerid = po.customerid
where c.type = 'business'
```

Comment: I realize that I forgot a critical part of the question... I need `product_order` to reference `customer` (so that the only records in `product_order` reference a `customer` record with `type = 'business'`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need another type for the type. This sample is in MS SQL format:

```
    CREATE TABLE TYPES (ctype varchar(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
         name varchar(50) not null
    );

    CREATE TABLE product_order (
           id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
           type varchar(10) NOT NULL REFERENCE TYPES (ctype) , 
           ....
    );
```

So your product_order must have types defined in Types table. In your sample, you have only one entry 'business' but you can add as many as you want.

Comment: I realize that I forgot a critical part of the question... I need `product_order` to reference `customer` (so that the only records in `product_order` reference a `customer` record with `type = 'business'`).

Comment: If you want to reference specified records, you may need a trigger.